# In Table View Controller Method -View Will Appear is not executing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

### In My Application

### 1) Login View

2)

-View

-Tab View Controller

-Navigation Caontroller

```
 -Table View Controller---Class  Name someTableViewController.h & .m

   -Table View
```

-Navigation Caontroller

```
 -Table View Controller

   -Table View
```

-Navigation Caontroller

```
  -Table View Controller
    -Table View
```

---

I am Starting from Login View and After successfull login

First the View Controller from 2) is  loaded and

from that MY Tab View Controller Table View is Loaded..

Every thing is going fine but

If I debug the Application I can not see the View Will Appear method is executing of

someTableViewController.

View didLoad Works Fine of same .h and .m file.

As I want to reload the Data.

I just have done Delegate and Datasource connection to TableView Controller. 
I think table View will appear is executing some delegate method?

Comment: have u write viewwillApperar method in ur code?

Comment: Yes but ein execution sequence app is ommitting(skip) it.

Comment: are you debugging in debug mode or release mode?

Comment: I am debugging by simple break points....

Comment: ya but in upper left side of your xcode you specified simulator and debug? or device and debug?

Comment: y u are not reloading tableview in viewDilLoad?

Comment: because as I am using the navigation controller In hierarchy I am going through table cells, and getting back to the table view again so in this case it will be never going to the view didload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Application **Navigation** based? if not what do you do when click on the "Back" button.

Try the following code:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

For **DetailView** from **TableView** use the following code:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView_obj animated:YES];
```

Comment: Actually but on that page I do not have self.navaigation controller I just have to load a new view....